# How to select an option in dropdown list htmlhelper

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, enums, html-helper

I have an enum like this.

```
public enum WeekDay
{
    Monday,
    Tuesday,
    Wednesday,
    Thursday,
    Friday,
    Saturday,
    Sunday
}
```

And I'm using it in this htmlhelper

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Day,
   new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(WeekDay))),
   "Select day",
   new { @class = "form-control" })
```

How can I make the dropdown list select one of those days instead of showing that "select day"?

Comment: What is `Day` (is it type of `WeekDay`)?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Day, new
 SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(WeekDay))), null, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

this will result in selecting the first entry in your list. In this case `Monday`